# Can I run spark independently without using oozie?

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have installed oozie and I can run spark job on oozie workflow? Can I run spark independently from the spark library in oozie bundle without using oozie directly. How can I do it? Please explain with an example.

Answer (score 3):

you can use spark-submit to submit jobs in spark-shell. Check the below spark documentation.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit

Comment: I have not installed spark but have installed oozie which lets me run spark job using its workflow. I want to run spark without using the oozie-workflow.

Comment: And I can't find spark-submit file in any of oozie's subfolder. How could I run it then.

Comment: @dark_shadow As far as i know Oozie is a work flow automation tool. It can't run a spark job independently.

Comment: You are right. Oozie is a workflow automation tool. But it has its own bundled tools like pig, sqoop, hive, etc. and it uses its own bundled tools for workflow execution. I just want to uses its bundled tool for my independent tool testing rather than install my own and then test.